# How to initialize char[] from a define

Tags: c, arrays

I want to copy my define into my var IP:

```
#define IP_ADDR {169, 254, 0, 3}

struct
{
  // ....
  char IP[4];

} COM_INFO;

memcpy(COM_INFO.IP, IP_ADDR, 4);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: first you wanted to copy `4 * sizeof(int)` bytes but not only 4-bytes. Second `IP_ADDR` is not an array!!

Comment: `memcpy(IP, (unsigned char[4])IP_ADDR, 4);` if C99

Answer (score 2):

Your `define` must be like this:

```
#define IP_ADDR ((unsigned char []){169, 254, 0, 3})
```

Now you can use `memcpy` on it.

**Example Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IP_ADDR ((unsigned char []){169, 254, 0, 3})

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char ip[4];

    memcpy(ip, IP_ADDR, 4);

    printf("%u.%u.%u.%u\n", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

> 169.254.0.3

Answer (score 1):

`IP_ADDR` will be pasted wherever its referenced (by the pre-processor). So, you could do something like the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize the COM_INFO structure.
    COM_INFO comInfo = { 
        // ...
        IP_ADDR,  // {169, 254, 0, 3} will be pasted here
        // ...
    };

    return 0;
}
```